# JavaScript проблема с текстом при возвращение

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка "Развернуть" при нажатие на кнопку текст должен поменяться на "Свернуть" и при повторном нажатие вернуться в исходное состояние (Развернуть)
Вот заготовка

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
img {
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    transition: 3s;
}
.kart {
    height: 300px;
    transition: 3s;

}
</style>
<body>
<img src="1555494_1461016165200_full.jpg">
<button>Показать</button>
</body>
<script>
let btn = document.querySelector('button')
let img = document.querySelector('img')

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    img.classList.toggle('kart')
    btn.textContent = 'Свернуть'
})
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    btn.textContent = btn.textContent === 'Свернуть' ? 'Развернуть' : 'Свернуть';
})
```

```html
<button>Развернуть</button>
```

Comment: Ок,все работает спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой есть интересный вариант + дополнительно с картинкой:

```js
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  $(".hidden").slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).html(function(i, html) {
    if (html.indexOf('Развернуть') != -1) {
      html = html.replace('Развернуть', 'Свернуть');
    } else {
      html = html.replace('Свернуть', 'Развернуть');
    }
    return html;
  }).find('img').attr('src', function(i, src) {
    return (src.indexOf('https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1812/PNG/64/4213478-action-add-button-more-new-plus-round_115393.png') != -1) ? 'https://icon-icons.com/icons2/1416/PNG/32/arrows-square-minus_97890.png' : 'https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1812/PNG/64/4213478-action-add-button-more-new-plus-round_115393.png';
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}

p {
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="toggle">Развернуть<img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1812/PNG/64/4213478-action-add-button-more-new-plus-round_115393.png"></p>
<div class="hidden">Скрытый текст</div>
```

Comment: а мне ваш ответ больше понравился. Реально можно использовать на сайте для сокрытия блоков текста

Comment: Я видел и подумал сразу, что много, что-то неприятностей человеку сразу свалилось (((